# Posting to Twitter through OAuthSimple.js

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-chrome-extension, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've been stuck on this one for a while. I'm trying to use OAuthSimple.js to interact with Twitter in a Chrome extension I've written.

The signing process seems to work fine for requests to retrieve a user's statuses, but I can't seem to construct a request that will successfully authenticate when I try to retweet, reply, or mark a tweet as favorite.

I'm following the guides [here](https://github.com/jrconlin/oauthsimple). I have also tried numerous ways of structuring the request, and comparing the request contents against the output of the OAuth tool provided by Twitter ( which seems to check out ), but I'm still getting 401 errors and generic "We couldn't authenticate you" responses.

Here's how I'm trying to form the request:

```
var sendTwitterRequest = function(url, params, method, callback) {

  var request = null;

        if ( localStorage.twitterAuthToken ) {
            OAuthSimple().reset();
            request = OAuthSimple(TwitterConsumerKey,TwitterConsumerSecret).sign({
                action:method,
                method:"HMAC-SHA1",
                dataType:"JSON",
                path:url,
                parameters:params,
                signatures:{
                    oauth_version:'1.0',
                    oauth_token:localStorage.twitterAuthToken,
                    oauth_secret:localStorage.twitterAuthVerifier
                }
            });

            console.log(request);

            $j.ajax({
                url:request.signed_url,
                type:method,
                data:request.parameters,
                success:callback
            });     

        }
    };
```

Then, making calls into this method like this:

```
  // this works, I get the data and can do stuff with it
  sendTwitterRequest('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=',null,'GET',someMethod());

  // this fails and throws a 401 error every time 
  sendTwitterRequest("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet/"+tweetKey+".json",null,'POST',someOtherMethod());
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the requests I am creating are fine, I just needed a final one to exchange request tokens for OAuth tokens. I thought this step was covered when the user was prompted for input, but turns out I was wrong.

I also ended up switching from OAuthSimple.js to just OAuth.js, on account of the fact that I could only get OAuth.js to process both the token requests and the timeline requests.

Some of this is pretty specific to what my application is doing, so you will probably need to modify it.

The new sendTwitterRequest method:

```
var sendTwitterRequest = function(options){

        var accessor={
            consumerSecret:TwitterConsumerSecret
        };

        var message={
            action:options.url,
            method:options.method||"GET",
            parameters:[
                ["oauth_consumer_key",TwitterConsumerKey],
                ["oauth_signature_method","HMAC-SHA1"],
                ["oauth_version","1.0"]
            ]
        };  

        if(options.token){
            message.parameters.push(["oauth_token",options.token])
        }

        if(options.tokenSecret){
            accessor.tokenSecret=options.tokenSecret
        }

        for(var a in options.parameters) {
            message.parameters.push(options.parameters[a])
        }

        OAuth.setTimestampAndNonce(message);
        OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message,accessor);

        try {
            $j.ajax({
                url:message.action,
                async:options.async||true,
                type:message.method||'GET',
                data:OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters),
                dataType:options.format||'JSON',
                success:function(data) {
                    if (options.success) {options.success(data);}
                }
            });
        } catch ( e ) {
        }

    };
```

And the methods that depend on it:

```
// asks Twitter for an oauth request token. User authorizes and the request token is provided
requestTwitterToken = function() {  
    // this is semi-specific to what my extension is doing, your callback string may need
    // to be slightly different.
    var callbackString = window.top.location + "?t=" + Date.now();

    var params = [
        [ 'oauth_callback', callbackString ]
    ];

    sendTwitterRequest({
        url: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
        method: 'POST',
        parameters: params, 
        format: 'TEXT',
        success: function(data) {
            var returnedParams = getCallbackParams(data);
            if ( returnedParams.oauth_token ) {
                chrome.tabs.create({
                    url:"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + returnedParams.oauth_token
                });
            }
        },error:function( e ) {
            console.log( 'error' );
            console.log( e );
        }
    }); 
};

// exchanges the Twitter request token for an actual access token.
signIntoTwitter = function(token, secret, callback) {
    var auth_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";

    var authCallback = function(data) {
        var tokens = getCallbackParams(data);

        localStorage.twitterAuthToken = tokens.oauth_token || null;
        localStorage.twitterAuthTokenSecret = tokens.oauth_token_secret || null;

        callback();
    };
    try {
        sendTwitterRequest({url:auth_url, method:'POST', async:true, format:'TEXT', token:token, tokenSecret:secret, success:authCallback});
    } catch ( e ) {
        console.log(e);
    }

};
```

With this, the steps are as follows:

- ask Twitter for a token ( `requestTwitterToken()` ) and provide a callback
- in the callback, check to see if a token is provided. If so, it's an initial token
- pass the token back to Twitter and open the Twitter auth page, which allows the user to grant access
- in the callback to this call, see if an access token was provided
- exchange the request token for an access token ( `signIntoTwitter()` )

After that, I simply use the `sendTwitterRequest()` method to hit Twitter's API to fetch the timeline and post Tweets.

Comment: I am trying to allow a user to sign in through OAuth, then send a tweet (all using just JavaScript), and I'm having major difficulty working with these libraries. I tried a bunch of different ones, and can't seem to get any working with Twitter. I'm not even sure if what I want to do is possible. Any chance you can post/link to some of your code so I can see how you do things? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I could probably do that, give me a few moments :)

Comment: Any luck? Still trying to sort this out.

Comment: The code examples are up there; if you'd like a more detailed discussion I'd be happy to chat with you about it offline.

Comment: Ok, well I suppose I have only one main question so I may as well just ask it here. You mentioned you were building a Chrome extension which can make cross-domain requests I think. What if I wanted to do this with just plain JavaScript? I could use JSONP, however, then I don't think it's possible to send custom headers which seem to be needed for authentication. So, unless I'm missing something, it's impossible to access the Twitter OAuth API through just JS with cross-domain AJAX disabled. So - am I missing anything?

Comment: The same domain policy only applies to scripts that are provided by a web server; which is why extensions, user scripts, or local scripts can make AJAX requests to other domains. If you're developing a page script, then I believe you are correct; JavaScript will not be able to directly make the calls you need. However, you could write JavaScript that makes calls to controllers in your web application that can act as delegates for the REST calls into Twitter you need to make...